# After returning a vector as double*, when read it, it is different

Tags: c++11

I am trying to return an array of doubles. When my function returns it, and then I try to read from it in `int main` it is telling me the value is 0.

We see this in the screenshot below.

My minimal verifiable example is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

double* pi_sequence(const int& len)
{
  vector<double> ests(len);
  double first = 3.123;
  ests[0] = first;
  cout << "first " << first << " ests.at:" << ests.at(0) << endl;
  return ests.data();
}

int main() {
  double* ests = pi_sequence(1);
  std::cout << "after returned: " << ests[0]  << std::endl;
}
```

Can you please help me understand why it is 0 after the return, and why it doesn't stay.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Answer (score 2):

Upon exiting `pi_sequence` function, `vector<double> ests` is destroyed.

Since `data()` returns a pointer to the underlying array then it points to invalid memory when returning to the caller, since that memory is released by `vector<T>` destructor.

Why don't you just return the vector itself by value? It will be optimized by [RVO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision#Return_value_optimization) (or move semantics) in any case so you won't get much difference.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a pointer to something that no longer exists. Since the `vector` is local to the function, it no longer exists when the function returns. So a pointer to the objects that were in the vector is now a pointer to whatever junk, if anything, happens to be stored where the vector was before.

Think about it -- what `double` do you think you're printing? No `double`s exist at that point in the code. If you're thinking "the first `double` in the `vector`", ask yourself *what* vector. The `ests` vector is out of scope and if you called `pi_sequence` again, a new one would be created.

Comment: If I put `static ests` inside the `pi_sequence` function, then i seem to be able to access right? Does `static` make it get allocated on heap? And I have to manually clear it up doing `delete returnedEsts`?

Comment: If you use `static`, there will be one and only one such vector and it will exist for at least `main` and any function called from it. You *can't* `delete` it if its `static`. The `delete` function is part of C++'s dynamic allocation and a static object can't be deleted on demand or it wouldn't be static.